# How to pass data or data array while rendering view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My URL is:

> `http://localhost/CodeIgniterCms/admin/dashboard/otherpages/123`
>   where,

Codeigniter Cms

```
- admin

-- dashboard (the controller)

--- otherpages (Method)
```

Controller code

```
public function otherpages($somedata) {
   $this->render('admin/second_view',$somedata);
}
```

Code in second_view.php

```
<pre>
   <div class="container">
     <?php echo $somedata;?>
    </div>
</pre>
```

But it is throwing error
Unable to load the requested file: admin/123.php

Comment: Do you have any special routing? Because the default is `localhost/class/function/data/` and your url doesn't quite correspond to it.

Comment: Yes, I removed index.php using .htaccess and routed my admin application and public application by declaring route config in route.php

Comment: Can you include the relevant routing information? That would help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this within your `otherpages` function:

```
$data['somedata'] = $somedata; <br/>
$this->load->view('admin/second_view',$data);
```

Comment: My code is `$this->render('admin/second_view',$somedata);`<br/> actually i am having a MY_Controller inside application/core, which is rendering template for me loading master_header and master_footer. I am embedding the link, I have created my application according to that only.<br/>{link}(http://avenir.ro/create-cms-using-codeigniter-3/)